# regular expression to replace a pattern

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

I use `Microsoft Visual Studio` and have a file with some text delimited by `|` . I need to find a particular pattern and remove it from the file

```
sometext|maxusage=sometext,,,,...|somemoretext
```

I want to isolate any `|` followed by `maxusage=` , followed by any text upto next `|`

in the above case, I need to isolate

```
|maxusage=sometext,,,,...|
```

Comment: try this pattern "\|maxusage=[^\|]+\|"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its simple and single statement

```
File.WriteAllText("c:\\test.txt", Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText("c:\\test.txt"), "\|maxusage=[^\|]+\|", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is C# code my friend,

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
  public static void Main()
 {
   string pattern = @"\p{Sc}*(?<amount>\s?\d+[.,]?\d*)\p{Sc}*";
  string replacement = "${amount}";
  string input = "$16.32 12.19 £16.29 €18.29  €18,29";
  string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
  Console.WriteLine(result);
 }
}
```

// The example displays the following output: 
//       16.32 12.19 16.29 18.29  18,29

Answer (score 0):

Note that it certainly works (it would not in case visual studio doesn't implement lazy quantifiers):

```
/\|maxusage=.*?\|/
```

Comment: without the ?, it selects the text from |maxusage to end of line.. with ?, it does not select anything

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `\|maxusage.*?\|`

Comment: hi, without the ?, it selects the text from |maxusage to end of line.. with ?, it does not select anything

Comment: text '|d|d|d|d'`\|.*?\|` will catch `|d|` , and `\|.*\|` will catch `|d|d|d|`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `string.Split()` in order to split your string and investigate it?

```
string[] parts = text.Split('|');
foreach(string s in parts){
//iterate of array and find what you are looking for
}
```